# Is this a correct application of 'exists' in Coq?

Tags: coq

In the simple example below I get the error **Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness.**
The lemma seems rather trivial so I guess, I'm not using the quantification properly.

```
Lemma exists_0 : forall n: nat, (exists m: nat, n = m).
Proof.
  lia.
Qed.
```

I've used this proof as a template:

```
Lemma le_antisym : forall n m: nat, (n <= m /\ m <= n) -> n = m.
Proof. 
  lia. 
Qed.
```

Any help on what would be a correct witness or, more preferably, how to prove similar existence statements, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/micromega.html#grammar-token-F), it does not seem that the decision procedure for lia handles existential quantifiers, so you have to instantiate the existential by yourself, e.g.

```
Lemma exists_0 : forall n: nat, (exists m: nat, n = m).
Proof.
  intros n; exists n.
  lia. (* but reflexivity is enough here *)
Qed.
```